# Writing an API response to a separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, fs

my goal is to get the api response (translated string) which currently shows in the console.log saved/written in a separate local file. I appreciate any help

```
const translate = require('google-translate');

translate('Translate this to japanese', { to: 'ja' }).then(res => {
    console.log(res.text); 
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/learn/writing-files-with-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NodeJS, you can use `fs` module to work with file. In this module, you can use `writeFileSync` method to write a string to a file.

```
const translate = require('google-translate');
const fs = require("fs");

translate('Translate this to japanese', { to: 'ja' }).then(res => {
    console.log(res.text); 
    fs.writeFileSync("translate_res.txt", res.text);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Checkout the NodeJS fs documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)